# How to calculate iteration Matrix in Gauss Seidel

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to solve a system through Gauss-Seidel Iterative method. But i also want to receive as an answer the iteration matrix that was used. I have this method

```
function [x0,iter] = gaussSeidel(A,b,iterMax,tol)

D = diag(diag(A));
Lower = -tril(A,-1);
Upper = -triu(A,1);
M = D - Lower;
N = Upper;
n = size(A);
n = n(1);
x0 = ones(n,1);
iter = 1;
for i = 1:1:iterMax
    iter = i;
    x = M\(N*x0+b);
    normC = norm(x-x0,inf);
    x0 = x;

    if normC <tol
        break
    end
end
```

I want to know whats in the iteration matrix **((D-Lower)^(-1))*Upper**, but for that I would have to calculate the inverse, and that's computationally expensive, is there another way to get the value?

Comment: Well, the "\" operator solves the lower triangular system on every iteration which should be equivalent in complexity to inverting it. So just using M\N should give you the answer you're looking for. Perhaps I have misunderstood the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"\" is an optimized way of solving linear constant coefficient systems by taking inverse.
If you want to see what is the inverse of the coefficient matrix, then you must use

```
inv(A)
```

instead of

```
A\b
```

There is no way out! Or if you are only dealing with the *N th* column of the inverse matrix, then you can also use

```
I=eye(n);
A\I(:,N);
```